# Emberjs save record Mockjax

Tags: ember.js, mockjax

I want to save a record and add to an existing list in emberjs.
I use two forms to simulate multiple models with the same property. But the main focus is on the 2nd one with books.

http://jsbin.com/pexolude/46

I use `books: store.find('book',{})` where i dont really know whats the empty object is for but it prevents to have the book record to appear on the list. I only want to have it **after** the save.

Is it possible to set mockjax's respons accordingly the posted data, so i sont have to use a hardcoded JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember-form doesn't appear to handle switching models out underneath it.  When you do `store.find('foo',{})` you're tricking Ember into finding by query.  When it finds by query it only includes the records returned in the results in the collection.  When you do `find('foo')` it returns a live collection that updates when any record is added or removed from the store.  You can do a find, then `toArray` to avoid having it be a live collection.  Then you can manually add the record to the collection, and swap out the currently editing model with a new record.  Unfortunately, as stated before Ember-forms doesn't update the binding and keeps using the same record.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var store = this.store;
        return store.find('book').then(function(books){
          return {
            books: books.toArray(),
            book:store.createRecord('book'),
            person: store.createRecord('person'),
            category: [{id:1,"name":"Fantasy"},{id:2,"name":"Drama"}]
          }
        });
    } 
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    some_action: function() {
      var self = this;
      this.get('model.book').save().then(function(record){
        var newRecord = self.store.createRecord('book');
        self.get('model.books').pushObject(record);
        self.set('model.book', newRecord);
        console.log(newRecord);
      }, function(error){
          console.log('fail');
      });


    }
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/pexolude/48/edit

Comment: kingpin2k thank you kingpin again. "Ember-form doesn't appear to handle switching models out underneath it" thats a big issue for me. I want to have my lists and forms on the same page. Is there any workaround to have a record bound to the form, save itm and add a clean record to the form, ready to save it. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I completely agree.  It isn't maintained by the Ember Team, I'd recommend submitting a bug report to their github page.